# Tooltip inside Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to include a `tooltip` in my `ng-repeat`, inside a `td` and it's not working.  I know it's not clear but here's the thing I have a `<td>` every time i want to hover the mouse to that each item of that `<td>` there's a `toolip` with more details.  My code is below. I am using `ng-if` because of null results.  I don't want to display an empty column.

```
<table  class="table table-bordered"   >
<thead><tr class="infoti" >
<th>Id Dev</th>
<th>Nom Dev </th>
<th>Nom Ecu</th>
<th>Etat</th>
<th>Action</th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>     
<tr dir-paginate=" dev in devs | itemsPerPage:7  ">

<td >{{dev.id}}</td>
<td>{{dev.nomdev}}</td>
<td >{{dev.ecu.nomEcu}}</td>    
<td ng-if="dev.validationdvd[0].etatvalid == 'Validé' "><a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Validé </a>

</td>
<td ng-if="dev.validationdvd[0].etatvalid != 'Validé' ">Non Validé</td>                 

<td>
<button class="btn btn-gray" ng-click="displaydata(dev.id)"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Validé</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="tooltip top" role="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">
{{dev.id}}
</div>
</div>
```

i initialized tooltip like this it worked outside the ng-repeat but it doesn't work how i  described it

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any guidance !!

Comment: why don't use ui-boostrap's tooltip.?

Comment: Its maybe too late for that but next project ill use it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching i found the solution , first you have to create a directive :

```
myApp.directive('tooltip', function () {
return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        $(element)
            .attr('title',scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip))
            .tooltip({placement: "right"});
    }
}
})
```

then you specify what you want to display in the tooltip i didn't paste my code code because like this it's more general so everyone could use it , finally you use it in html like this

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <a rel="tooltip" tooltip="item.whatever_you_want_to_display_inside_the_tool_tip">{{your Displayed item}}</a>
```

hope it helps you